# MySQL string encoding for Geometry package

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with an encoding problem.

I have a MySQL table containing a list of coordinates in a 'polygon' column. Polygons are all disjoints. I want to use the ST_Contains() function to find in which polygon is a point. Here is my SQL query (x and y are doubles):

```
SELECT id_polygon
FROM polygons
WHERE ST_Contains(polygon, POINT(x,y))
LIMIT 0,1;
```

When I tried this query, server respond with an error message:

```
ERROR 3055 (HY000): Geometry byte string must be little endian.
```

After some search, I modified the charset of the column with:

```
ALTER TABLE polygones MODIFY polygone mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf16le;
```

But i still have the same error. I'm out of ideas. :/

If you need more informations, don't hesitate !

P.S. : I pasted below an example of a polygon entry :

```
46.120052 4.926273,46.120692 4.921995,46.126637 4.921996,46.129165 4.909363,46.135851 4.909232,46.144537 4.91604,46.157977 4.903081,46.160961 4.904571,46.180433 4.910603,46.182715 4.914132,46.183046 4.932896,46.173769 4.938714,46.164259 4.932778,46.153246 4.958286,46.145964 4.943331,46.12938 4.939155,46.120871 4.931056,46.120052 4.926273
```

Answer (score 0):

your column should be of type 'polygon' or 'geometry'. If you can't do that by any reason, use this function: ST_GeomFromText(polygon).